# How to debug a Facebook chatbot?

Tags: facebook, vagrant, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I am working on a basic Facebook chatbot, but ATM I need to deploy the code I want to test, and this means pull request, merge, deploy, bla bla.

Is there a way to expose a url from my vagrant box in order to speed up the development?

thanks

M

Answer (score 0):

One of the best tool is probably https://ngrok.com/ that can help you open a tunnel between your local environment and the world. For Vagrant you can use Vagrant Share which uses ngrok see documentation here : https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/index.html